# weird thing. working fiddle doesn't work on html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

weird thing.

my http://jsfiddle.net/48Hpa/19/ doesn't work when I write all to html http://jsbin.com/AYEQEJE/1/edit  I checked everything . I have all the `DOM ready` things and so, too.

Comment: Please post the code in SO itself, may be working logic can be in a jsfiddle.

Comment: Seems like it works to me. Your CSS is a little off in the jsbin version though.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/AYEQEJE/7/edit please see this i add jquery ui library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your JSbin, it seems you're missing to add **jQuery UI css** file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
```

Once added it is working.  See the corrected [**JSBin link**](http://jsbin.com/AYEQEJE/10)

Comment: This is correct, when i tested it (for my answer) I didn't realise it auto added the CSS.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I didn't know jsfiddle included jqueryui.css automatically.